# Why are we allowed to change values of "const" qualified variables?Why pointers are allowed for this,but not assignment?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, assignment-operator

Consider the following 2 programs **prog1** and **prog2**.Here if I try to change the value of the `const` qualified variable `i` using a pointer `ptr`,I get the warning (not error) `"initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type|"`,but the program runs nevertheless and displays the new value. But if I try to change the value of `i` in the second program using an assignment statement, I get the **error**(not warning)   `assignment of read-only variable 'i'|`.

Here are confusions arising from this premise:

1. Why are we allowed to change the value of a read-only `const` qualified variable in any circumstance? Doesn't it defeat the purpose of using a `const` qualifier? Shouldn't we get an error if we attempt to do so?
2. Even if due to some strange reason we are allowed to change values of constants, why the discrimination between changing the value of a read-only `const` qualified variable using a pointer (which is allowed, with a warning) and through using an assignment operation (which is simply not allowed and gives us an error)?

```c
// prog1
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    const int i=8;
    int *ptr=&i;
    *ptr=9;
    printf("%d",*ptr);  //Prints new value nevertheless
}
```

**warning:** initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type|

```
//prog2
#include <stdio.h>
           
int main()
{
    const int i=8;
    i=10;
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

**error:** assignment of read-only variable 'i'|

**EDIT for H2CO3**

Here I change the value of the `const` qualified variable more than once.I only get a warning,the same as in `prog1`

```
//prog3
#include <stdio.h>
   
int main ()
{
    const int i=8;
    int *ptr=&i;
    *ptr=9;
    *ptr=10;
    printf("%d",*ptr); // Prints 10
}
```

Comment: Corrected 2 typos.OK now.

Comment: Why? because, for mostly historical reasons (and bad practice habit), the C standard has been so defined, or so implemented. (It probably is different in C++).

Comment: You fail to realize that, prog1 has no violations, at no moment do you change anything that is const. you set your pointer to a const'd pointer, and change that pointer. try `int const* ptr = &i` and try again.

Comment: @Shark Prog1 **does have** constraint violations.

Comment: Because C compilers trust the programmer and do not try to fix programmers errors.

Comment: @H2CO3 wouldn't prog1 just have undefined behaviour instead of a compilation error? I do not see how prog1 will throw any compilation error, but I do see how it could crash at runtime.

Comment: @Shark I didn't say it had a compiler error. It has a constraint violation, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1) Why are we allowed to change the value of a read-only `const` qualified variable in any circumstance? Doesn't it defeat the purpose of using a `const` qualifier?

Trying to change a const-qualified object through an assignment operator is a constraint violation:

6.5.16 under **Constraints**:

> 2 An assignment operator shall have a **modifiable lvalue** as its left operand.

Modifiable lvalues are defined in 6.3.2.1 (1):

> A *modifiable lvalue* is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, **does not have a const-qualified type**, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.

As a constraint violation, it requires a diagnostic message from the compiler per 5.1.1.3 (1):

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.

But an implementation is not required to reject invalid programmes, so the diagnostic message could also be a warning instead of an error.

However, modifying an object that is declared `const` through an lvalue that has not const-qualified type is not a constraint violation, although it invokes undefined behaviour, 6.7.3 (6):

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

Since it's not a constraint violation nor invalid syntax, it doesn't even require a diagnostic message to be emitted.

> Shouldn't we get an error if we attempt to do so?

You *must* get a diagnostic message if you try to modify an object through an lvalue with const-qualified type.

Since that an egregious violation of the declared intentions, most compilers emit an error in these circumstances.

If you try to modify an object with const-qualified type through an lvalue with non-const-qualifed type as in

```
const int i=8;
int *ptr=&i;
*ptr=9;
```

the attempt to modify `i` through the expression `*ptr = 9` invokes undefined behaviour, but is not a constraint violation (or syntax error), hence does not require a diagnostic message (and none is given).

There is a diagnostic message emitted for the initialisation

```
int *ptr = &i;
```

because that is again a constraint violation, per 6.5.16.1 (1):

> One of the following shall hold:
>
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right has arithmetic type;
> - the left operand has an atomic, qualified, or unqualified version of a structure or union type compatible with the type of the right;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, **and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right**;
> - the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand is an atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer, and the right is a null pointer constant; or
> - the left operand has type atomic, qualified, or unqualified _Bool, and the right is a pointer.

That diagnostic is however usually a warning and not an error because one may explicitly cast the `const` away,

```
int *ptr = (int*)&i;
```

whereas one cannot cast away the `const` from `i`.

Modifying an object through a pointer to a non-const-qualified object type which has been obtained by casting away the `const` from a pointer to a const-qualified object type is valid *if the object pointed to is modifiable*. Stupid example:

```
int i = 8;
const int *cptr = &i;  // valid, no problem adding const
int *mptr = (int*)cptr;
*mptr = 9;             // no problem, pointee is non-const
```

> 2) Even if due to some strange reason we are allowed to change values of constants, why the discrimination between changing the value of a read-only const qualified variable using a pointer (which is allowed,with a warning) and through using an assignment operation (which is simply not allowed and gives us an error)?

Directly assigning to an object with const-qualified type is not only a constraint violation, but also an obvious violation of the stated semantics. Declaring an object `const` explicitly says "I don't want that object to be modified".

Modifying an object through a pointer to a non-const-qualified type is not a constraint violation, and only undefined behaviour if the pointee has const-qualified type. Converting a pointer to a const-qualified type to a pointer to the corresponding non-const-qualified type is allowed, and modifying the pointee through that pointer may be valid, therefore you get only a warning, and only if the conversion is not made explicit.

In the given short example, the compiler could detect that the pointee has const-qualified type and therefore the modification invokes undefined behaviour, but in general such would be difficult, and often impossible to detect. Therefore, the compiler doesn't even attempt to detect the simple cases, it's not worth the effort.

Comment: It will be nice of you if you can have a look at the following question as well,maybe leave a comment, as I am not sure if it merits your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543795/what-exactly-does-const-int-ptr-i-meanwhy-is-it-accepting-addresses-of-non/16545257?noredirect=1#16545257

Comment: I see Eric Postpischil beat me to it. His answer is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks,new-found respect for Eric Postpischil now!!

Answer (score 2):

> Why are we allowed to change the value of a read-only `const` qualified variable in any circumstance?

We aren't. I don't see why you assume that, nor which example shows that.

> why the discrimination between changing the value of a read-only const qualified variable using a pointer (which is allowed,with a warning)

Again: it's **not allowed,** hence the warning. (Warnings are **to be taken seriously** - you don't seem to give any significance to them...) It's just that the compiler doesn't know that the pointer points to some `const`-qualified object (because it's declared as non-const `T *`).

As to why changing the variable works:

Explanation #1: it's undefined behavior (a constraint violation), so it can do anything.

Explanation #2: probably it's just stored on the stack like local automatic variables, and you can indeed change it.

Comment: I used a pointer to a `const` qualified variable to change the value multiple times.Aren't we supposed to be allowed to only initialize it once.Just a minute.I am posting an edit.Check **edit**.

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture  `int *p = &foo;` <- here `p` is **not** const-qualified. I also don't see the relevance for changing it mulkiple times. Assignment is not initialization, be it one or more assignment.